# sbt assembly failing due to conflicting file

Tags: scala, hadoop, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to make a fat jar by running sbt assembly for my project.
I am getting the following error :

```
[error] (root/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/xyz/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.class
[error] /Users/xyz/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/jars/hadoop-core-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.1.jar:org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.class
```

DistributedCache of hadoop-mapreduce-client-core is deprecated now.
In my build.sbt I have included :

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.7.1" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.servlet"))
```

The dependency is like this :

```
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.2.0 
 org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:2.2.0
  org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:2.2.0
```

How do I handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if you intend to remove the dependency jar of mapreduce-client-app when it is being load when you rely on hadoop-client:2.2.0, just simply add intransitive:

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0" intransitive()
```

This will only include the hadoop-client:2.2.0 jar and exclude all its dependencies.